# Why should js function's name starts with a capital letter

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function. I used only simple letters for the name of that function. I didn't get any output and error. I highlighted this function.

Lesson3.js

```
import React from 'react'

    function formattedDate(props){
    return(
    <div>This is {props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}</div>
    );
}

class Clock extends React. Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {date:new Date()}
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.tick(),1000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.timerID)
    }

    tick(){
        this.setState({
           date : new Date()
        })

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div><h1><formattedDate date={this.state.date}/></h1></div>
        );

    }

}

export default Clock
```

So I checked my entire code. But I didn't catch any bugs. After I changed the function name to the uppercase name, I got the output. Please explain the reason for that.

```
import React from 'react'

function FormattedDate(props){
    return(
    <div>This is {props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}</div>
    );
}

class Clock extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {date:new Date()}
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.tick(),1000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.timerID)
    }

    tick(){
        this.setState({
           date : new Date()
        })

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div><h1><FormattedDate date={this.state.date}/></h1></div>
        );

    }

}

export default Clock
```

I imported Lesson3.js to App.js. There's no bug in my code except that error I mentioned above.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Clock from './Components/lesson3'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

        <p>
          <Clock/>
        </p>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you have tried to use `FormattedDate` as a `component`. Not as an ordinary function.

All React component names must start with a capital letter. If you start a component name with a lowercase letter, it will be treated as a built-in element like a `<div>` or a `<span>`. This is because of the way JSX works.

You can find more information [here](https://blog.pusher.com/troubleshoot-react-errors/)

Answer (score 2):

It's a naming convention to use capitalized variable/function names for components, to distinguish them from regular/helper/etc functions.

```
function Button() { return <button>Test</button> }

function sortNumbers(array) { return ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags. 
For example, `<div />` represents an HTML div tag,
So in :

1. `<formattedDate .../>` React treat as DOM tag, Obviously which it is not

On otherhand `<UpperCase />` represents a component and requires it to be in its scope

2. So, `<FormattedDate />` represents a component and requires FormattedDate to be in scope.

If you want to learn more about component you can read more [at React Offical docs for component and props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)